# Add input field value to a dynamically added row using jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(".add-row").click(function(){
   var  x= $("#name"). val ();
   $("table").append("(tr)  (td)  (input type="checkbox"/)  (/td)  (td)  /(td)");
})
```

Here I am adding a row with two columns in a table using jQuery when a user clicks the button.
In one column I am showing a checkbox while in the other column I want the name which I am storing in variable x. But it is taking a string as a argument, I don't know how can I pass value of x.
What should I write in the   column so that it will print value of x not "x" itself.
I am using () instead of <> cauz I dont know why <> is not visible in the code.

Comment: I have edited the code, please change it to the correct code (Replace `()` with `<>`)

Comment: You're not even using `x` inside `.append` is this your full code?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your code, see the string that you are passing in append, tilt symbol (`) is the best choice while passing such sting in javascript, see the below script

```
$(".add-row").click(function(){
   var  x = $("#name").val();
   $("table").append(`<tr><td><input type="checkbox" value="${x}" /> </td> <td>/<td>`);
});
```